# How to set image transparent for non-transparent part from another image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have two images: `img1` and `img2`, and `img2` is transparent except for one part of the image.

Using Pillow, how to crop the non-transparent part of `img2` from `img1`? As a result, I would like to get `img1` with transparent part, where `img2` is non-transparent.

`img1` and `img2` are the same size.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Brian I am passing through all pixels from start to end (row by row) and checking pixel by pixel and  transparency in img2, it works but I am wondering is there any better solution then this n^2 solution.

Comment: Considering adding the code your wrote to accomplish all that to your question with an [edit].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your Pillow images to NumPy arrays and make use of vectorized operations to speed up your processing.

Having `img1.png` (fully opaque random pixels)

[image: img1]

and `img2.png` (fully transparent background pixels, fully opaque red pixels)

[image: img]

one could use this approach to achieve the described behaviour:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Open images via Pillow
img1 = Image.open('img1.png')
img2 = Image.open('img2.png')

# Convert images to NumPy arrays
img1_np = np.array(img1)
img2_np = np.array(img2)

# Get (only full) opaque pixels in img2 as mask
mask = img2_np[:, :, 3] == 255

# Make pixels in img1 within mask transparent
img1_np[mask, 3] = 0

# Convert image back to Pillow
img1 = Image.fromarray(img1_np)

# Save image
img1.save('img1_mod.png')
```

The modified `img1_mod.png` would look like this (fully opaque random background pixels, transparent pixels where there's the red square in `img2.png`):

[image: img1_mod]

If you have "smooth" transparency, i.e. your alpha channel has values from the whole range of `[0 ... 255]`, we could modify the code. Having such an `img2_smooth.png`

[image: img2_smooth]

that'd be the modified code:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Open images via Pillow
img1 = Image.open('img1.png')
img2 = Image.open('img2_smooth.png')

# Convert images to NumPy arrays
img1_np = np.array(img1)
img2_np = np.array(img2)

# Get (also partially) opaque pixels in img2 as mask         # <--
mask = img2_np[:, :, 3] > 0                                  # <--

# Make pixels in img1 within mask (partially) transparent    # <--
img1_np[mask, 3] = 255 - img2_np[mask, 3]                    # <--

# Convert image back to Pillow
img1 = Image.fromarray(img1_np)

# Save image
img1.save('img1_smooth_mod.png')
```

And that'd be new output `img1_smooth_mod.png`:

[image: img2_smooth_mod]

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
NumPy:       1.18.1
Pillow:      7.0.0
----------------------------------------
```